# Writing to all members in etcd v3 benchmark

Tags: etcd3

The following is what is used to [benchmark](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/op-guide/performance.md#benchmarks) "write to all members".

```
# write to all members
benchmark --endpoints=${HOST_1},${HOST_2},${HOST_3} --conns=100 --clients=1000
put --key-size=8 --sequential-keys --total=100000 --val-size=256
```

My understanding is that only the leader listens to write requests. So how is it possible to write to all members of an etcd cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secondary nodes just forward the write requests they receive to the leader.